# WTFforms field values initialised when not desired

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a WTFforms "user add" form which takes common attributes for a user and commits them to a database. The values of these html form fields are being populated on page load when not desired.

I have not set any jinja code to set the fields and in the route for this page I have not passed a user to the render_template call.

The fields of the user form and the user class are very similar as you would expect

**User Object**

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
firstname = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=False)
surname = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=False)
email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
num_records_added = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, default=0)
num_records_edited = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False, default=0)
role = db.Column(db.String(20), index=False, unique=False, default='Editor')
```

**User form**

```
class AddUserForm(FlaskForm):

firstname = StringField('First name', validators=[DataRequired()])
surname = StringField('Surname', validators=[DataRequired()])
email = StringField('Email address', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
role = SelectField('Role', choices=[], validators=[DataRequired()])
password = PasswordField('password', validators=[DataRequired()])
num_records_added = IntegerField('Number of Records Added')
submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

My assumption is that there is interaction between the logged in user via flask_login and the form because they share similar atributes/fields.

To prove this I modified the form so that each field has a trailing "_" as part of it's name and updated the route/template to work with this new naming style and the problem goes away.

Can someone explain what is happening here and what is the correct approach to avoiding this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem and it turns out to be the autofill behaviour of lastpass that was causing the issue.

It was filling in the fields with the information it had as id/labels of the form field match up with it's entry for the website.

I assume this could happen for other autofill behaviours of browsers.

In this case I have to accept that I need to use ids for the form fields which do not match these automatic fill fields use otherwise they will be populated.